# Can a Website detect what browser extensions are being used?

Tags: extension-methods

Can a website detect what browser extensions are being used?  Specifically in this case, the author of the extension wishes to **prevent** websites from identifying when users are using the extension.  So, for a generic example, could the programmers at Yahoo! write code so that www.yahoo.com could tell when it's users were using Firebug?  And if Yahoo! could do this, is there anything that the makers of Firebug could do to prevent this?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you can detect some of them in Firefox using javascript, here is an article:

http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.com/2006/08/i-know-what-youve-got-firefox.html

and one more:

http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20060823/detecting-firefox-extentions/

here is how it is detected:

```
// popular extensions.
var e = {
 "Adblock Plus" : "chrome://adblockplus/skin/adblockplus.png",
 "Auto Copy" : "chrome://autocopy/skin/autocopy.png",
 "ColorZilla" : "chrome://colorzilla/skin/logo.png",
 "Customize Google" : "chrome://customizegoogle/skin/32x32.png",
 "DownThemAll!" : "chrome://dta/content/immagini/icon.png",
 "Faster Fox" : "chrome://fasterfox/skin/icon.png",
 "Flash Block" : "chrome://flashblock/skin/flash-on-24.png",
 "FlashGot" : "chrome://flashgot/skin/icon32.png",
 "Forecastfox" : "chrome://forecastfox/skin/images/icon.png",
 "Google Toolbar" : "chrome://google-toolbar/skin/icon.png",
 "Greasemonkey" : "chrome://greasemonkey/content/status_on.gif",
 "IE Tab" : "chrome://ietab/skin/ietab-button-ie16.png",
 "IE View" : "chrome://ieview/skin/ieview-icon.png",
 "JS View" : "chrome://jsview/skin/jsview.gif",
 "Live HTTP Headers" : "chrome://livehttpheaders/skin/img/Logo.png",
 "MeasureIt" : "chrome://measureit/skin/measureit.png",
 "SEO For Firefox" : "chrome://seo4firefox/content/icon32.png",
 "SEOpen" : "chrome://seopen/skin/seopen.png",
 "Search Status" : "chrome://searchstatus/skin/cax10.png",
 "Server Switcher" : "chrome://switcher/skin/icon.png",
 "StumbleUpon" : "chrome://stumbleupon/content/skin/logo32.png",
 "Tab Mix Plus" : "chrome://tabmixplus/skin/tmp.png",
 "Torrent-Search Toolbar" : "chrome://torrent-search/skin/v.png",
 "User Agent Switcher" : "chrome://useragentswitcher/content/logo.png",
 "View Source With" : "chrome://viewsourcewith/skin/ff/tb16.png",
 "Web Developer" : "chrome://webdeveloper/content/images/logo.png",
 "Unhide Passwords" : "chrome://unhidepw/skin/unhidepw.png",
 "UrlParams" : "chrome://urlparams/skin/urlparams32.png",
 "NewsFox" : "chrome://newsfox/skin/images/home.png",
 "Add N Edit Cookies" : "chrome://addneditcookies/skin/images/anec32.png",
 "GTDGmail" : "chrome://gtdgmail/content/gtd_lineitem.png",
 "QuickJava" : "chrome://quickjava/content/js.png",
 "Adblock Filterset.G Updater" : "chrome://unplug/skin/unplug.png",
 "BBCode" : "chrome://bbcode/skin/bbcode.png",
 "BugMeNot" : "chrome://bugmenot/skin/bugmenot.png",
 "ConQuery" : "chrome://conquery/skin/conquery.png",
 "Download Manager Tweak" : "chrome://downloadmgr/skin/downloadIcon.png",
 "Extended Cookie Manager" : "chrome://xcm/content/allowed.png",
 "FireBug" : "chrome://firebug/content/firebug32.png",
 "FoxyTunes" : "chrome://foxytunes/skin/logo.png",
 "MR Tech Disable XPI Install Delay" : "chrome://disable_xpi_delay/content/icon.png",
 "SessionSaver .2" : "chrome://sessionsaver/content/ss.png",
 "spooFX" : "chrome://spoofx/skin/main/spoofx.png",
 "Statusbar Clock" : "chrome://timestatus/skin/icon.png",
 "Torbutton" : "chrome://torbutton/skin/bigbutton_gr.png",
 "UnPlug" : "chrome://unplug/skin/unplug.png",
 "View Source Chart" : "chrome://vrs/skin/vrssmall.png",
 "XPather" : "chrome://xpather/content/iconka.png", 

};

if (is_mozilla) {
 showExtensions(); 
}

function showExtensions() {
 for (var i in e) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.setAttribute("border", '0');
  img.setAttribute("width", '0');
  img.setAttribute("height", '0');
  img.setAttribute("onload", "document.getElementById('ext').
appendChild(document.createElement('li')).innerHTML='" + i + "'");
  img.setAttribute("src", e[i]);
 }

}
```

So, looks like to prevent this kind of detection you don't need to have unique resources that can identify plugin or name your resource the same name as existing plugin to mask.

Comment: Nice find. Another one (same method, but more extensions): http://www.phpsolvent.com/wordpress/?p=1888

Comment: Thank you, Romario.  Your answer has definitely pointed me in the right direction.  It sounds like if I either don't use images (not great but ok) or have the user disable javascript (bad), the user can use a Firefox extension anonymously.  Could a website search for other (non-image) files within my extension?  Also, do you know how this issue is in IE or Google Chrome?

Comment: Well, my guess is some resources are accessible, it could be that only those images are in order to show them on the addon page. As for the IE - they use ActiveX as addon format, there are functions to see if ActiveX is installed, so if you know the name you can detect if it is there.

Comment: You can read more here about plugin detection: http://www.rgagnon.com/jsdetails/js-0056.html

Answer (score 2):

This information is not part of http protocol and if server-side is getting requests from browsers it can barely influence what kind of information is in http header. The only way it might be done is via JavaScript, so that you, as a programmer, create javascript that gets this information out of browsers. But only in case that the browser has available functions for this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I use this to auto-fill a hidden form field when users are requesting help, so I know if there is a plugin causing problems:

```
var plugins = "";
for (var i = 0; i < navigator.plugins.length; i++)
{
    plugins += navigator.plugins[i].name;
    if (i != (navigator.plugins.length - 1))
    {
        plugins += ", ";
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was about Extensions, not plugins. (Try `javascript:navigator.plugins[0].name` in your Firefox address bar to see the name of the first plugin)

Comment: +1, even if this doesn't answer the question, this is a really great idea!

Comment: Plugins and extensions and add-ons all mean the same thing to me.

Comment: They are not. In firefox plugins help your browser perform specific functions like viewing special graphic formats or playing multimedia files. Plugins are slightly different from addons, which modify or add to existing functionality, addons are written in javascript, plugins could be C++ code.