# Can web applications be secured against browser extensions?

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome-extension

It seems there are a vast number of browser extensions that exhibit malicious behavior. Additionally, even valid extensions could suffer from security vulnerabilities that make them behave maliciously.

One way to avoid this problem is to package your web application with a platform like NWJS, Electron, or similar. This has the advantage of removing the extension ecosystem, but also suffers from a number of drawbacks (installation process, more resource consumption, increased labor, and more).

Some have argued that "*In the end it's the user's responsibility, not the website's fault that the user is compromised*". While that makes a good point, those of us responsible for software that manages sensitive data still have a duty to protect.

When writing a web application that will access sensitive data, is there *anything* that can be done to secure against browser extensions?

---

**Edit:** Any creative solutions to this problem would be great. Alternatively, a confirmed negative would also be welcome. Some trails of thought that extend from this question:

- Can the window object be protected or somehow made private?
- Are there any restrictions to an extension's JavaScript that loads *before* the page that could be used to the web application's advantage?
- Can a companion extension detect other extensions and then communicate to the web application that it is unsafe to run? Or at least notify the user of the potential for abuse?
- Are extension background scripts also injected into iframes and child windows create by calling window.open? Perhaps the web application would replace the window object with different ***safe*** copy of a window object.
- Might there be some clever way to detect if third-party code has been run on the page? A sort of "hash" of the JavaScript environment?

Comment: no.............

Comment: You can abuse bugs in the extensions API. For example in modern Chrome extensions can't intercept AppCache. There may be other holes.

Comment: I thought web extensions have to be approved and signed after undergoing a review process.  Is that no longer accurate?

Comment: @Gary - I've published a few private extensions but don't recall needing anything approved / signed / reviewed. Even if they are... that puts the onus of security on the body that manages the extension ecosystem. Since there's already been a significant number of reported malicious extensions (google it), I'd say that system is failing.

Comment: It'd be great to find a comprehensive solution for protecting against these.

Comment: I know only of what can be found on MDN concerning Mozilla web extensions. The rules appeared restrictive, such as the extension has to be self contained such that an externally requested script cannot be run, which is what I was considering to add extra features.  But, whether or not all of that can be completely verified is a different matter.  From reading Mozilla Disourse my impression was that it was getting more strict. But I know very little of it.

Comment: @epascarello - that extended ellipsis in your comment... do you have the time to elaborate?

Comment: Sure, if the extension can run, it can execute code. There is not much you can no to prevent it to run. Just like how you can detect ad blockers but not really do much to keep it from running.

Comment: @epascarello - thanks. I've added some additional ideas to the question. In the case of ad blockers, the web application *is* doing something though - it detects the ad blocker and typically hounds the user to disable it. While not perfect, it's a start. If the page can in some way detect third-party code and warn the user that they may be compromising sensitive data, that would be better than doing nothing.

Comment: This may be a bit *trenchant*, but if you need security the solution is to *not* use a web browser (or anything akin to that). On the other hand, banks seem to think that browsers are secure enough to handle your financial data. Unless you are dealing with weapons of mass destruction (or any other life-or-death situation) I doubt you need more security than that.

Comment: How would you be able to detect it? Only reason they know that a ad blocker is there because they are looking for it. There really is no generic thing you can do to detect that a random extension alters your code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a (primitive) solution to detect user extensions **installed** on the browser, from there I guess you can deny the access to your web application until the user uninstalls these extensions. It consists in a small database of assets (icons), if the javascript can find these assets, it means the extension is installed.

CONS: You can't detect if the extensions are running, therefore if the user disables them that won't be detected and you will still get a positive.

The code is in this link:

[Can a Website detect what browser extensions are being used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078765/can-a-website-detect-what-browser-extensions-are-being-used)

Post with users feeding this database with more assets:

https://blog.jeremiahgrossman.com/2006/08/i-know-what-youve-got-firefox.html

Comment: This would require the developer to 1) Compile a list of assets from all known browser-extensions AND keep that list up-to-date. 2) Make a fetch request for each and every extension. This option does not seem viable.